# Pygame under macOS Catalina (Trying to use pygame 2.0.0.dev6)

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Im trying to use pygame in MacOS Catalina, but video doest work, I saw in other thread that someone managed to get it work by installing pygame 2.0.0.dev6.

I got it with:

```
python3 pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

but i got the error:"Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"

i tried to solve this with:

```
python3 pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6 --user
```

but now it says:

> "Requirement already satisfied: pygame==2.0.0.dev6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.0.0.dev6)"

but when I execute:

> python3 import pygame

it is still in version 1.9.6

any ideas in how do i change the pygame version?

(Sorry for my english, and im new in python, if this has a very simple solution)

Comment: Wait, how come `python3` is installing packages in `/Library/Python/2.7` - the directory for Python 2.7? Are you sure you're executing `python3` and not just `python`?

Comment: It should be `python3 -m pip`, not `python3 pip`.

Comment: @ForceBru
you were right, i was using just python, i executed:
'python3 -m pipinstall pygame==2.0.0.dev6' as hoefling said and i worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install python 3.8.2 and try running "python3 pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6" in the command line again. Then go to where you have the python 3.8.2 package installed and run that specific IDE. Try importing it from this IDE.

Hope this helps!